# How do I access the Databricks table format column

Tags: azure, databricks

I can display the Databricks table format using: DESCRIBE {database name}.{table name};
This will display something like:

format  id    etc.
 hive  null   ...

Is there a way to write a SQL statement like:

SELECT FORMAT FROM {some table} where database = {db name} and table = {table name};

I would like to know if there is a Databricks catalog table that I can query directly. I want to list all of the Databricks tables that have a "format = 'delta'".

Answer (score 0):

Unlike a relational database management system, there is no system catalog to query this information directly.

You need to combine 3 spark statements with python dataframe code to get the answer you want.

```
%sql
show databases
```

This command will list all the databases (schemas).

```
%sql
show tables from dim;
```

This command will list all the tables in a database (schema).

```
%sql
describe table extended dim.employee
```

This command will return detailed information about a table.

[image]

As you can see, we want to pick up the following fields (database, table, location, provider and type) for all tables in all databases.  Then filter for type 'delta'.

Databricks has the unity catalog in **public preview** right now.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/

Databricks has implemented the **information schema** that is in all relational database management systems.  This is part of this new release.

https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-information-schema.html

[image]

In theory, this statement would bring information back on all tables if the unity catalog was enabled in my service.  Since it is not enabled, the query processor does not understand my request.

In short, use spark.sql() and dataframes to write a program to grab the information.  But this is a lengthy task.  A easier alternative is to use the unity catalog.  Make sure it is available in your region.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

To return the table in format method, we generally use “Describe Formatted”:

```
DESCRIBE FORMATTED [db_name.]table_name

DESCRIBE FORMATTED delta.`path-to-table` (Managed Delta Lake)
```

You cannot use select statement to get the format of the table.

The supported SQL – select statements.

```
SELECT * FROM boxes

SELECT width, length FROM boxes WHERE height=3

SELECT DISTINCT width, length FROM boxes WHERE height=3 LIMIT 2

SELECT * FROM VALUES (1, 2, 3) AS (width, length, height)

SELECT * FROM VALUES (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4) AS (width, length, height)

SELECT * FROM boxes ORDER BY width

SELECT * FROM boxes DISTRIBUTE BY width SORT BY width

SELECT * FROM boxes CLUSTER BY length
```

For more details, refer “[Azure Databricks – SQL Guide: Select](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/select.html)”.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does not solve the problem.  Find all tables that are in delta format.